# Check activity of SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to check if a SQL DB (SQL Server 2016) is still in use. Well, how can I get it?

My approach is to check all logs to verify if someone is still inserting, deleting, selecting data and so on.

For that I have checked Management --> SQL Server Logs. But there, I just can find 13 files. It looks like that there isn´t enough information.

I tried too with the next query:

```
SELECT conn.session_id, sson.host_name, sson.login_name, 
 sqltxt.text, sson.login_time,  sson.status, sson.database_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections conn
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions sson 
ON conn.session_id = sson.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle) AS sqltxt
ORDER BY conn.session_id
```

It is returning just information of myself, connecting to the DB now.

Finally I tried with the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
```

But mostly the information that appears doesn´t contain data in **Begin_Transaction** and **End_Transaction** fields and I feel like I am losing information.

Am I doing something wrong? Do you know another better option?

Many Thanks.

Comment: The SQL Server Logs don't don't log activity against a database, they log against the instance. You would likely be better off setting something like Extended Events.

Comment: @Larnu. I just checked and I don´t have permission to create a New Session. Are these Extend Events recording all new activity? I need to check the activity from now to back (So, I can know if some of my old colleague is still using it). Any other approaches?

Comment: "Now to back"? What does that mean?

Comment: @Larnu. Sorry. I need to check if the DB is being used now or it was used during the last year. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to check in the last year, you'll need to check whatever logging processes you have in place that record activity. If you have none, then there are none.

Comment: @Larnu. Ok, there are none so. Many Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to stop the SQLServer service and see if any users complain.

Comment: You're responsible for determining if a database is in use but you don't have the rights to create things like Extended Events sessions which could be used to audit database use? Anyway the most effective way to determine if a database is in use is called a scream test - you set the database offline and wait for someone to scream.

Comment: Hahahaha. Yeah, right. But we want to avoid that. We are the owners of the application and the DDBB and the servers and the so on, but there are several departments in charge of the different aspects of the different components of the application